# Battery draining faster after installing Juno

Tags: release-juno, battery

Since I've upgraded to Juno. My battery is draining faster than ever.

Usually, my laptop stays on for 4 hrs with 100% Charge now it's reduced to 2 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should install tlp for some battery saving. Is helped me so much, almost +2 hour of battery life compared to windows.

```
sudo apt-get install tlp
```